# How to make (link)button function as hyperlink?

Tags: asp.net, button, hyperlink, webforms, linkbutton

How do I use an `asp:Button` or `asp:LinkButton` as `asp:Hyperlink`?

The existing Hyperlink just goes to another section on the same page: `NavigateUrl="#Section2"`

I want to do this in the aspx file without additional coding. Thanks.

The purpose is to have a button look instead of the underlined text BUT **I don't want to use an image with hyperlink** to achieve this purpose.

Comment: why to do that and not direct use a Hyperlink ?

Comment: Back to HTML basics (as commented by Aristos): Why would you even consider ASP.Net controls for such? There is no rule in ASP.Net that you "should" always use controls. A simple [hyperlink](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) will do. You can `style` it as you wish...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use OnClientClick event to call a JavaScript function:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclientclick='redirect()' />
```

JavaScript code:

```
function redirect() {
  location.href = 'page.aspx';
}
```

But i think the best would be to style a hyperlink with css.

Example :

```
.button {
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e2;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work the redirect on click... should that be single quote?

Comment: Yes, this redirect() method is not working properly, we get inside the method but location.href = 'page.aspx'; does not redirect to page.

Answer (score 19):

There is a middle way. If you want a HTML control but you need to access it server side you can simply add the `runat="server"` attribute:

```
<a runat="server" Id="lnkBack">Back</a>
```

You can then alter the `href` server side using `Attributes`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       lnkBack.Attributes.Add("href", url);
    }
}
```

resulting in:

```
<a id="ctl00_ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_contentPlaceHolder_lnkBack" 
      href="url.aspx">Back</a>
```

Comment: This solution uses an anchor, not a button.  To use this method you must also consider the visible display of the link which may require some CSS manipulation.

Answer (score 9):

The best way to accomplish this is by simply adding "href" to the link button like below.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="SomeLinkButton" href="url" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Button Text</asp:LinkButton>
```

Using javascript, or doing this programmatically in the page_load, will work as well but is not the best way to go about doing this.

You will get this result:

```
<a id="MainContent_ctl00_SomeLinkButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="url" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$lSomeLinkButton&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Button Text</a>
```

You can also get the same results by using using a regular 
`<a href="" class=""></a>`.

Comment: Nice and simple. Not sure why I didn't think to do this... Perfect for what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This can be done very easily using a PostBackUrl and a regular button.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Name of web location" PostBackUrl="web address" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use linkbutton for navigating to another section in the same page by using `PostBackUrl="#Section2"`