# Use linkbutton to open a link within the same tab

Tags: asp.net, ascx

I have a .net project and I've been trying to use a `linkbutton` in a such a way that it will not open the link on another page/tab. At the moment what I have open the link on another page.
Please help.

My ascx page code below:

```
 <td>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="ApproveButton" runat="server" Text="Approval" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" OnClientClick="window.open('/Licence-Application/Applicant-Approval-Page');"/>
</td>
```

I have tried `window.open`, `window.show`, `Response.Redirect`, `window.location`, `location.href` with no luck.
It's either it keeps opening the same page or gives an error or open on a new tab.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make (link)button function as hyperlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034960/how-to-make-linkbutton-function-as-hyperlink)

Comment: Can you tell us a little more of the error you're getting when you try `location.href`?

Comment: Below is the error I got on using 'location.href' 
'Error: Enrolled Applicants List is currently unavailable. DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: The server tag is not well formed. ---> System.Web.HttpParseException: The server tag is not well formed. ---> System.Web.HttpException: The server tag is not well formed. at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessError(String message) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to use `location.href` instead of `window.open`. `window.open` will always open a new tab.

```
<asp:Button ID="ApproveButton" runat="server" Text="Approval" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" OnClientClick="location.href = '/Licence-Application/Applicant-Approval-Page';"/>
```

or

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="ApproveButton" href="/Licence-Application/Applicant-Approval-Page" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Button Text</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Not sure what he's doing here but this solution definitely works. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14035072/238631) out.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta is right. I only used 'location.href' but I just tried only 'href' and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.